# How to put a real values in SQL query using postgreSQL?

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I have some problems with an application developed in Java that uses postgreSQL as a DB. I managed to make a dummy query as follows:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO voicemessages (UNIQUEID,MSGNM,DIR,CONTEXT,MACROCONTEXT,CALLERID, ORIGTIME,DURATION, FLAG,MAILBOXUSER,MAILBOXCONTEXT,RECORDING, LABEL, read ) "
                  + "VALUES (1, 1, 'dir/dir1/msgs', 'message', 'message', '6001', '15/01/2015 13:31:25', '1:32', 'flag', 'Georgi Georgiev', 'Georgi Georgiev', '12314124', 'some label', false);";
```

And it works perfect when I execute the statement. A row in the DB is created and I am able to display the data using:

```
SELECT * FROM voicemessages;
```

The problem is when I create my own VoiceMail class and when I create an object from this type and put in the query the getters and setters for this object I receive some kind of an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "dir" does not exist Hint:There is a column named "dir" in table "voicemessages", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.Position: 169
```

I am trying to insert a row by using and executing this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO voicemessages (UNIQUEID,MSGNM,DIR,CONTEXT,MACROCONTEXT,CALLERID, ORIGTIME,DURATION, FLAG,MAILBOXUSER,MAILBOXCONTEXT,RECORDING, LABEL, read ) "
                  + "VALUES (" + message01.getUniqueId() + ", " + message01.getMessageNumber() + ", " + message01.getDirectory() + ", " + message01.getContext() + ", " + message01.getMacroContext() + ", " + message01.getCallerId() + ", " +message01.getOrigTime() + ", " + message01.getDuration() + ", " + message01.getFlag() + ", " + message01.getMailboxUser() + ", " +message01.getMailboxContext() + ", " + message01.getRecording() + ", " + message01.getLabel() + ", " + message01.getRead()+ ");"+" ";
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to quote strings.
This  ", " + message01.getDirectory() + ", "  will become  ", '" + message01.getDirectory() + "', "

Comment: Don't create statements like that. Use a `PreparedStatement`. Not only does your current problem go away but you are also safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you! 
Quoting solved it and now I will try to use PreparetStatements instead.
: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Direct values use parameters for safety, What happens is that the SQL statement you pass is parsed to prepare and compiled by the database. So by sending the actual SQL separately from the parameters, you limit the risk of SQL injection